# Qual o tipo de locução de "de colapso" nesta frase?

Tags: adjetivos, advérbios, locuções-adverbias, voz-passiva

Na frase "ameaça de colapso", a locução "de colapso" é adjetiva ou adverbial?

Tenho a seguinte explicação:

> ... o termo em negrito é uma locução **adverbial**, pois o valor é de passividade, ou seja, se invertemos a ordem e inserirmos um verbo na voz passiva, a frase manterá seu sentido. Veja:
>
> Ex.: **Colapso foi ameaçado**.
>
> Essa frase faz sentido e apresenta valor passivo, logo, sem o verbo, a locução destacada anteriormente é adverbial.

Haveria outra forma de justificar a função de advérbio da locução "de colapso", ou então, de complementar essa resposta?

Porque eu acho essa resposta meio estranha.
Parece-me estar errada: "Colapso foi ameaçado" parece não preservar a ideia original.
E, como a apostila se limitou a esse motivo, também achei insuficiente.

Outra explicação que lá dão é que locução adjetiva tem valor de posse, mas eu acho que tampouco é o caso aqui.

Eu entendo como sendo uma locução adjetiva que caracteriza o tipo de ameaça.

Comment: Tentei tornar a pergunta mais clara, espero ter ajudado. Podes reverter corrigir ou melhorar as edições, claro, à tua vontade! Para isso, vê o [histórico](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/9452/revisions) da tua pergunta (clicando em "edited X mins ago") ou usa o link "[Edit](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/9452/edit)".

Comment: Acho que seria útil explicares porque achas a explicação estranha, isso clarificaria a tua dúvida e ajudaria uma resposta a acertar exatamente no que procuras. :)

Comment: No meu conhecimento pedestre, parece-me uma locução adjetiva (vendo, e.g., [aqui](https://www.normaculta.com.br/locucao/) e [aqui](https://www.normaculta.com.br/locucao-adjetiva/)).

Comment: Você poderia adicionar um link para a (suponho) apostila que oferece essa explicação?

Comment: @stafusa Infelizmente não.

Comment: @ANeves Sem problemas. Obrigado pela correção. Eu achei a explicação esquisita por conta dessa conversão para voz passiva. Parece estar errado: "Colapso foi ameaçado" parece não preservar a ideia original. E, como a apostila se limitou esse motivo, também achei insuficiente.

Outra explicação que dão é que locução adjetiva tem valor de posse, mas, eu acho que tampouco é o caso aqui. Eu entendo como sendo uma locução adjetiva que caracteriza o tipo de ameaça. O que acha?

Comment: Da validade ou qualidade dos argumentos, não acho nada porque esta área escapa um pouco aos meus conhecimentos. Mas da explicação da estranheza da explicação, acho muito útil e incluí-a na pergunta! :)

Comment: Em português, é preciso dizer: Um colapso ou O colapso etc.